# Clone permissions from identical folders recursively

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions

There are identical folders with almost the same content/structure from two different machines but the permissions are different.

How can I copy all permissions from folder A to folder B **recursively** to trickle down to all subfolders and files with same name and skip anything that is not.

There is a command, for example:

```
chown --reference=otherfile thisfile
```

Is there a way to make it recursive or maybe any other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do this in the `-exec` part of find, but this works:

```
for file in $( find . -mindepth 1 ); do
   getfacl ${otherdir}/${file} | setfacl --set-file=- ${file}
done
```

It will copy ALL of the permissions, including Access Control Lists.

Comment: Shouldn't parse the results of find, you could use `-exec` or `xargs` instead.